# Free alternative to google calendar allowing categories

Tags: calendar, time-management, google-apps, google-calendar

I am looking for an alternative for google calendar that allows events to be categorized into different groups (which can be toogled by the users). So for instance that one wants to see only the events for "food" in the upcoming month. The calendar can be public, private team events are not needed. It has to be free as it is for a small non-profit organization.

Any suggestion highly welcome!

EDIT: Should mention that web options are prefered, but the organization has a little website, so hosting is also possible.

Comment: Have you considered simply making and sharing more than 1 google calendar?  You can have a calendar named "food" and another named "sports".  Users can simply click the square to turn that calendar on or off.  I have 70 calendars I can turn on or off.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I would rather keep everything in one place and let the user subset the available events based on their choices. The google calendar is currently inserted on the webpage as well and it is impractical to insert a couple of them...

Comment: @cybernard, this is precisely what I do.  For instance I have a separate calendar that I share with my wife.  Curlew, are you mistaking calendars for accounts perhaps ?  One can have more than one calendar for an account.

Comment: You can create a small menu bar down the left side, and when the user clicks **food** that calendar is displayed in the square.  When the user clicks **sport** the sport calendar is placed in the square.  Each calendar can has its own URL.  You create a html DIV or similiar and based on the menu item clicked the url in the DIV is updated the new URL.

Comment: You can get many free alternative to google calendar in this [blog](http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/15-cool-alternatives-to-google-calendar/).